# Shielded vs Twisted cables

Tags: audio, analog, shielding

For some reason low voltage, high quality audio interconnects seem to be made of 3 wires braided together, when normal low voltage audio wires are two wires surrounded by a grounding sleeve.

I'm a college student, and I think I understand exactly how both of these methods can cut down on "internal" interference, but if I'm correct then the braided wire method wont do poop when it comes to helping block external magnetic field, which is why the grounding sleeve is great because it acts as a Faraday cage around the signal bearing wire.

Is there something that I don't understand about braided wire that is somehow magically better than protected wire for carrying an analogue voltage?

So I guess my question is: why does a cable that looks like this...

[image]
Cost more than a cable that looks like this...

[image]

Comment: When you buy these kind cables (I assume you refer to High end brands) you pay for the materials used (like Teflon insulator, silver wire, plug quality) plus the research cost that goes into developing these products that usually include several patents. Of course there is also a cost related to the prestige of the company selling them.

Comment: @alexan_e, so what about the shielding quality of "twisted" pairs vs shielded?

Comment: They just cost more and are meant for amplifiers that go to "11". Besides, chrome makes cars go faster.

Comment: It costs more because it looks like that.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a [balanced audio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_audio) signal (e.g. XLR), then the idea behind a twisted pair is any interference that one wire picks up will also be captured by the other wire.  The device that receives the signal only cares about the *difference* between the two levels, so any common mode noise can be ignored.  This is extremely important for long runs (lots of opportunity for noise to intrude), or microphones (very low signals).  Good cables will also be shielded, as the wires aren't "perfectly twisted" with zero area between them, so are still slightly susceptible to interference.

However, with unbalanced audio (e.g. phono plugs, jack plugs, TRS (like your picture), etc...), you only have one conductor, so must totally shield it to prevent noise.  Still, such runs are both short and amplified, so the effect of interference will be smaller and is generally inaudible.

A "braided cable" like the one you picture is probably electrically worse than a typical foil-shielded audio cable.  Such a braid would also be counterproductive in balanced audio as the conductors are unnecessarily separated.

As for *why* they are braided that way, it's because it looks *kewl* (so they can charge more), and in that 6" cable, *nobody will ever hear the difference*.

Comment: Haha, that's what I thought.  Thanks for clarifying.  And it's worth noting that most good XLR cables are STILL shielded even though they are balanced.

Comment: @KeeganMcCarthy I did mention that "Good cables will also be shielded, as the wires aren't "perfectly twisted" with zero area between them, so are still slightly susceptible to interference."

Answer (score 2):

Balanced wiring to unbalanced interfaces is counterproductive and could introduce noise and distortion. Balanced line is a superior connection method when all the rules are followed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to distinguish magnetic shielding from electrostatic shielding.

A Faraday cage provides almost perfect shielding against electric fields.

It's quite difficult (without superconductors) to provide such shielding against magnetic fields. By twisting, braiding or using a Litzendraht (litz) arrangement, you can almost perfectly equalize magnetically induced voltage in both wires of a balanced circuit so that the common-mode rejection of a balanced input can reject the interfering signal.

Pro audio often uses [balanced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_audio) circuits, so it might make some sense. If it's just used on a single-ended signal, it's just window dressing and an excuse for them to charge extortionate prices. Note that you'd only get one channel through a balanced circuit using a 1/4" TRS connector as shown, not stereo.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see what the pictured cable is good for electrically. It looks like it's probably pretty good mechanically though. So for short leads that get bent and twisted around a lot and maybe have some weights dangling off them, it could be the superior choice.

Twisted Pair + Shield is the 'best' cable. But shields are expensive, increase cable weight and thickness.

A twisted pair can cancel out most noise. The usual method is to have your signal 180 degrees out of phase in each wire. So your signal pairs will be out of phase, but any noise introduced along the way should be in phase. Making it easy to drop the noise when it gets to the other end.

Twisted pairs are actually usually better than non-twisted shielded cable. I've personally never seen a case where twisted + shielded was required, only cases where engineers blamed cable noise for problems in end point designs.

Answer (score 1):

Bundling wires inside a shield creates more capacitance, and running audio signal through a capacitor creates a low pass filter, so high frequency signals can be lost. Braiding is done to minimize capacitance, and keep the wires together as a single unit since twisting without an outer sleeve would unravel. Headphone cables and extensions are generally short and not used in areas where there’s a lot of potential for interference, and the signal is already amplified, so shielding isn’t necessary.

Comment: Braiding minimizes inductance (the wires are still there same distance from each other when braided)

Answer (score 0):

Impedance is frequency dependent and capacitance affects frequency response. With balanced cable you are separating the positive phase of the signal from the negative phase and amplifying them separately. The signal can be sent with one phase reversed. As it passes from source to receiver both wires will pick up interference with identical phases for each at the same amplitude in each. The phase reversed line has its phase reinstated. Any rf disturbance that phase picked up is now cancelled between phases and the signal is clean.
Errors in that process will also be equal and opposite and should cancel too. So balanced signal transmission should have good common mode rejection and low distortion. You can send balanced signals very long distances without noticeable degradation. Braids, Litzendraht twisting and shielding attenuate the level of disturbance entering the cable and give even better results.
Expense comes from materials and material quality, the number of kilometres of the stuff you manufacture. The complexity of the structure. How quickly you can manufacture it. How easily the manufacture can be automated and productionised. Hand made stuff with a complex structure that can take a long while to make and wastes lots of materials has to be more expensive to make any profit. Then you will need to market it and advertise it. The pro industry cables all work to a standard so most cables work fairly similarly. Hi fi cables connect wildly varying specifications for input and output. So don’t be surprised that cable sound different and some work better in one situation than in another. If you are not curious about cables you can end up with a ho-hum performance from acclaimed components. So you have to find cables that sound accurate or, pleasing in your system.